# Save / restore dialog state using MFC for Windows 11 features

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, windows-11

My `CDialog` application supports remembering the position / state of the various dialogs. It uses logic that is freely available on the internet. Eg:

```
void CResizingDialog::RestoreWindowPosition(CString strWindow, CWnd* pWindow, bool bOverrideState)
{
    int     max_x{}, max_y{};
    RECT    rtWindow{};

    if (pWindow == nullptr)
        return;

    // Only restore if there is a previously saved position
    rtWindow.top = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Top"), -1);
    rtWindow.left = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Left"), -1);
    rtWindow.bottom = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Bottom"), -1);
    rtWindow.right = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Right"), -1);
    if (rtWindow.top != -1 && rtWindow.left != -1 &&
        rtWindow.bottom != -1 && rtWindow.right -1)
    {
        max_x = rtWindow.right - rtWindow.left;
        max_y = rtWindow.bottom - rtWindow.top;

        // Get a handle to the monitor
        HMONITOR hMonitor = ::MonitorFromPoint(
            CPoint(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        // Get the monitor info
        MONITORINFO monInfo{};

        monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
        if (::GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monInfo) == 0)
            AfxMessageBox(_T("GetMonitorInfo failed"));
        else
        {
            // Adjust for work area
            rtWindow.left += monInfo.rcWork.left - monInfo.rcMonitor.left;
            rtWindow.top += monInfo.rcWork.top - monInfo.rcMonitor.top;

            // Ensure top left point is on screen
            const CRect rcMonWork(monInfo.rcWork);
            const CRect rtRestored(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top, rtWindow.right, rtWindow.bottom);

            // Deflate the rectangle so we have a margin
            if (rcMonWork.PtInRect(rtRestored.TopLeft()) == FALSE ||
                rcMonWork.PtInRect(rtRestored.BottomRight()) == FALSE)
            {
                rtWindow.left = monInfo.rcWork.left;
                rtWindow.top = monInfo.rcWork.top;
            }

            if (m_bOnlyStorePosition)
            {
                // We must override the dimensions of the dialog. This is because the user
                // might have text scale in effect.
                CRect rtOrg;
                GetWindowRect(&rtOrg);
                // But we want to show it in the previous place (albeit slightly off position)
                pWindow->MoveWindow(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top, rtOrg.Width(), rtOrg.Height());
            }
            else
            {
                rtWindow.right = rtWindow.left + max_x;
                rtWindow.bottom = rtWindow.top + max_y;

                // Restore window size
                pWindow->MoveWindow(&rtWindow, FALSE);
            }
        }

        if (bOverrideState)
        {
            // Let us override by restoring the window state
            const int iState = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("ShowCmd"), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            pWindow->ShowWindow(iState);
        }
    }
}

void CResizingDialog::SaveWindowPosition(CString strWindow, const CWnd* pWindow)
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT wp{};

    if (pWindow == nullptr)
        return;

    pWindow->GetWindowPlacement(&wp);

    // Commit to registry
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Top"), wp.rcNormalPosition.top);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Left"), wp.rcNormalPosition.left);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Bottom"), wp.rcNormalPosition.bottom);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Right"), wp.rcNormalPosition.right);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("ShowCmd"), wp.showCmd);
}
```

My problem is when I resize my windows this way in Windows 11:

[image]

In the above scenario (maximize to right side of screen) my window is restored to the normal position because the `showCmd` value is 1 which is `SW_SHOWNORMAL`. If I maximize the window to the full screen then it does return as full screen because the `showCmd` value is 3 which is `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`.

So this brings me back to when users use the new GUI for resizing the window. Do do we also save / restore that state?

Comment: Aero Snap is a feature of the Shell, not the window manager. The window manager is unaware that there is some special property for a window that happens to occupy exactly the right half of the screen.

Comment: @IInspectable So there is no way for us to cater for this scenario?